# Regular Expression: match within a match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to use regex to find everything between two words which contains a specific word, however the words are repeated so I'm not getting the match I want.

For example I want everything between 'hello' and 'bye' such that the word 'apple' exists between them:

```
hello sometext hello sometext apple sometext bye sometext bye
```

The result I want is "sometext apple sometext", that is, the smallest amount of text such that the condition is met.

However if I use `hello((?s).*apple(?s).*)bye` then I get:

```
sometext hello sometext apple sometext bye sometext
```

Answer (score 4):

To consume all the `hello`s that come before the last one before `apple`,
put `.*` in front of the pattern:

```
r'.*hello (.*?apple.*?) bye'
```

Also, I'm not sure what you meant by `(?s)`.
In any case, the pattern above will give your desired result,
for example when used as `re.match(r'.*hello (.*?apple.*?) bye', s).group(1)`.

Finally,
as [@Rawing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/rawing) pointed out in a comment:

> [...] this regex will give you the *last* occurrence. For example if the input string is `hello apple1 bye hello apple2 bye`, you'll get `apple2`. So if you need to find more than one occurrence, this regex won't work.

... and as [@bobble-bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble) responded to that, you could find the first occurrence by using a lookahead like this:

```
r'hello((?:(?!hello).)*?apple.*?)bye'
```

Comment: This pattern works just as well with `re.match`. `re.search` is less efficient for no benefit. (Assuming a single-line input string, or dot-all modifier.)

Comment: Another thing I want to point out is that this regex will give you the _last_ occurence. For example if the input string is `hello apple1 bye hello apple2 bye`, you'll get `apple2`. So if you need to find more than one occurence, this regex won't work.

Comment: @Rawing Indeed, well-spotted

Comment: @Rawing probably could [use a lookahead like this](https://regex101.com/r/ZZE301/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble nice!

Answer (score 0):

Throw in a couple of word boundary's and this will match it.

`(?s)\bhello\b(?:(?!\b(?:hello|bye)\b).)*\bapple\b.*?\bbye\b`

Explained

```
 (?s)                 # Modifier: dot-all
 \b hello \b          # 'hello
 (?:
      (?!
           \b 
           (?: hello | bye )    # Not 'hello' nor 'bye'
           \b 
      )
      . 
 )*
 \b apple \b          # 'apple'
 .*?                  # the rest (note - this could match hello again)
 \b bye \b            # 'bye'
```